# How to pass an object into a function in vb6

Tags: object, vb6

Lets say i got couple Objects named as txt1 and another object as lbl1.
I have a function that should make changes on both of these objects, like highlighting.

I want to get the value of that object (doesnt matter which object) and than i want to highlight it.

Such as:

```
Function Highlight(Obj1 As Object, Obj2 As Object)

    MyTxt = Obj1.Text
    Obj1.Text = ""
    Obj1.SetFocus

    MyCap = Obj2.Caption
    Obj2.Caption = ""

End Function
```

How can i achive that?

Comment: What errors your current (sample) code raises?

Comment: It gives `Invalid Qualifier` error which means i cant use the object that way. But there must be a way to do it and i want to know how. also i dont understand why a person gives -1 to this question cause i should not know if a function can get any object reference this way or not im just trying and asking if its posible..

Comment: You do it in just the way you've said. How is this being called and what lien is failing?

Comment: Oh, and don't use `Function` unless it returns something, and if it does, specify a data type.

Comment: On what row exactly you get "Invalid Qualifier"?

Comment: @Arvo It gives the error at the lines where i use .Caption and .Text

Comment: Its being called as Highlight(txt1, lbl1) and it gives error at the lines where i use .Caption and .Text so @Deanna can you show me an example of returning data type?

Comment: Can you update your question with the exact code you're using. The calling code you say you use has a syntax error and allowing for the correction, works perfectly.

Comment: @Berker - If it's not too onerous, could you make use of `Option Explicit` and declare your variables through-out your project? That "Invalid Qualifier" error means that although the compiler can recognize the identifiers taken piecemeal, it still cannot figure out what object is actually being meant; a case of failed disambiguation.

Comment: Another thought just occurred to me - what are MyTxt and MyCap? Strings? Objects? How have they been declared?

Comment: @rskar MyTxt and MyCap are as you said strings..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Object` does not have a `.Text` or `.Caption` property.  Change your method to:

```
Sub Highlight(Obj1 As TextBox, Obj2 As Label)

    MyTxt = Obj1.Text
    Obj1.Text = ""
    Obj1.SetFocus

    MyCap = Obj2.Caption
    Obj2.Caption = ""

End Sub
```

Comment: I would be surprised if this is the issue. A VB6 Object implies the use of late-binding - which means it will literally search through the interface of the actual instance at run-time to locate a member by name.

Comment: I agree that Late binding should avoid issues with Text and Caption, by I like the answer because it declares the control types.  I suggest to the OP `Dim MyTxt As String`, `Dim MyCap As String`,  and `Option Explicit`.

Comment: Thanks now i understand how it happens.

Comment: +1 even though strictly the first sentence is misleading. But I agree the OP needs to learn to use early binding first, and learn more advanced topics later. @Berker you should always have an As *Type* clause on your variable declarations

Answer (score 1):

Check out [`TypeOf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ec5kw18%28v=vs.80%29.aspx):

```
if TypeOf Obj1 is TextBox then
   Obj1.text = "kkkkkk"
end if
```

Comment: i just went trough time and needed to look at this issue again and when i see your answer again i felt like: Damn!
Why dont i use this? Its really an awesome way to handle many objects in a loop..